# ReactJs useState .map() is not a function

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jsx

I am trying to understand how the `useState` and `useEffect` hooks works in ReactJs.

I get the error message

> .map() is not a function

when attempting to display data in a table.

```
const [posts, setPosts] = useState([]);

useEffect(() => {
    const alarmService = new AlarmService();
    const response = alarmService.getData();
    setPosts(response)
}, [])

return (
    <table className="table">
        <tbody>
        {posts.map(data => (
            <tr key={data.id}>
                <td>
                    <div className="row">
                        {data.name}
                    </div>
                </td>
                <td className="custom" >
                    <button
                        className="btn btn-danger btn-sm"
                        onClick={() => this.handleDelete(data)}
                    >
                        Delete
                    </button>
                </td>
            </tr>
        ))}
        </tbody>
    </table>
);
```

I assume the issue is in my `useEffect`, as I am not sure what to do with the response.

**SOLVED**

I looked into these examples: 
https://www.robinwieruch.de/react-hooks-fetch-data/

The trick was to create a async function within the useEffect. Like this:

```
useEffect(() => {
    async function test() {
       const alarmService = new AlarmService();
       const response = await alarmService.getData();
       console.log(response);
       setPosts(response)
    }
    test();
}, []);
```

Thank you to everyone who took their time to respond and help out!

Comment: Hi, can you please verify whether the "response" in `const response = alarmService.getData()`
 is an array?

Comment: Just noticed that the repsonse is a: Promise {<pending>}. Within that promise is the array. I assume the .map() function expects an array right?

Comment: I believe your problem is not related to react but with promises. I assume that the getData() is an ajax call. Meaning that when you do the setPosts(response) the response is either a promise or undefined, so map won't work. To bypass this you need to do the setPosts after the getData promise is resolved.

Comment: @JensOlsson you got the point. Just Resolve the promise and you should be good to go. Cheers

Comment: Try `const response = alarmService.getData().then(res => res.json());`

Comment: Ah, I see. I'll check it out. Thanks!

Comment: Unfortunately promises and useEffect are a bit of a mess. You might want to read this: https://dev.to/n1ru4l/homebrew-react-hooks-useasynceffect-or-how-to-handle-async-operations-with-useeffect-1fa8

Comment: That's an interesting article. Thank you. By the looks of this, I might have to reconsidering using useEffect.

Answer (score 1):

I think the problem here is that `alarmService.getData` is asynchronous and you are not  dealing properly with that. That's why you get Promise pending, and you can not map over posts.

```
useEffect(() => {
    const alarmService = new AlarmService();
    alarmService.getData().then(response => response.json()).then(data =>setPosts(data))    

}, [])
```

This   should fix your problem.

Comment: That makes sense! I'll look into it. Thanks for the heads up.

Comment: I would use async/ await like one of the cool kids. But yea, the thought that this is just improperly handled async data is definitely correct.

Comment: @JensOlsson Did it fix your issue though ?

Comment: @Noob I used a different solution that worked fine in my project. Thanks though!

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you are right. The problem is in the way we are updating state, i.e in useEffect method. While we are updating state, setPosts doesn't identifies if the posts is an array and updates state as simple object. Hence, you see the error.

You can find similar scenario in the codesandbox, when I am trying to add response in posts
https://codesandbox.io/s/ecstatic-flower-lq2r1.

Please uncomment the fix in codesandbox to see things working.