# ReactJS: JavaScript "Map" function says "is not a function" when trying to iterate on a "useState" array of objects

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am experiencing a problem that when I call the "map" function to iterate over a array of objects that was created using useState, I get a error saying that "map" is not a function.

It works fine if I use it on a manuually defined array like `const array = [a, b, c] but when using useState, it does not.

I created the array like this (Notice that I only pasted the parts that are actually doing this.)

```
// Etc

async function getFicharpgs(login_usuario) {
    // Step 1 - Get my JSON Data from my API.
    try {
        const response = await axios({
            method: "post", url: "http://localhost:3000/usuario_ficharpg/listar_fichas", data: {"login": login_usuario}
        });

        // Console Log prints perfectly (Printed image below.)
        console.log('getFicharpgs => Resposta completa:', response);
        console.log('getFicharpgs => Lista de Fichas do Usuário Recebida:', response.data);

        return response; // This returns my response data, including my JSON Data.

// Etc

function Ficharpg({objeto_props}) {
    const {login_usuario} = objeto_props;

    // Step 2 - Create my array list as a state variable to be passed on to another component
    const [ficharpgs, setFicharpgs] = useState([]);

// Etc

useEffect(() => {
        // Step 3 - Pass the data I got from my getter to my useState array.
        if (login_usuario) {
            // Espera a função assíncrona getUsers ser concluída antes de finalizar o efeito (Renderizar o Componente).
            getFicharpgs(login_usuario)
                // Implantacoes de Then/Catch para resolver "Promise Ignorada" e fazer regras de negocio.
                .then(response => {
                    // Entra aqui caso o nosso status tenha sido 200 - [Object object]
                    console.log(`Componente Ficharpg => Fichas de RPG do Usuario Recebidas com sucesso. Status: ${response.status}`);

                    // Mudo o estado para dizer que o carregamento dos dados terminou
                    setdadosCarregando(false);

                    // Here is where I add my data from my response into the state variable.
                    setFicharpgs(response.data);  // Step 3 Completed here.

// Etc

    // Render the data from my useState array.
    return (<div>
        {/* If Ternario que checa se os dados estao sendo carregados. */}
        {dadosCarregando ? (<p>Selecione qual usuário vai mostrar as fichas.</p>) : (<table>
            <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>Fichas de RPG do Usuario {login_usuario}</th>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <th>Nome</th>
                <th>Classe</th>
                <th>Raca</th>
                <th>Nivel</th>
                <th>Alinhamento</th>
            </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>

            {/* Step 4 - Iterate over my list and print my objects. */}
            {ficharpgs.map((ficharpg, ficharpg_id) => (
                // Index Key: ID da Ficha do RPG, identificador da nossa "linha" (Table Row) - Key => Built-In Do JavaScript.
                <tr key={ficharpg_id}>
                    <td>name: {ficharpg.nome}</td>{" "}
                    <td>age: {ficharpg.classe}</td>
                    <td>age: {ficharpg.raca}</td>
                    <td>age: {ficharpg.nivel}</td>
                    <td>age: {ficharpg.alinhamento}</td>
                </tr>
            ))}

// Etc
```

So, at step 4, I was expecting it to print my data from the array, but instead, I am getting the following error:

> ficharpgs.map is not a function
> TypeError: ficharpgs.map is not a function

I already tried to look into another posts from users that had the same problems, like this one:

[ReactJs useState .map() is not a function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57994107/reactjs-usestate-map-is-not-a-function)

But I was not able to fix it reading the answer from it. :(

**Edit**

Just a quick edit, here is the output of a console.log from inside my getter function that prints the response itself:

[image: Console Log from the Getter]

And this is the output of a console.log from inside my component, that prints my useState array:

[image: Console.log of my useState array]

Comment: The error is happening because `ficharpgs` is not an array. Try to `console.log` `response.data` value and see what you got.

Comment: Response.data actually gives me a JSON with my data. I pasted the images of both outputs. It is even described as "array" by the browser.

Comment: You set it to an object, not the array...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a common error that happens when the variable you referred to is not an array.

`map()` is a method of an array, so if the variable is not an array, it will throw this error.

As your screenshot says, the response of `getFicharpgs()` API call is an object, not an array.

So, you need to get the correct array:

```
getFicharpgs(login_usuario)
  .then(response => {
    // ...
    setFicharpgs(response.data.ficas_do_usuario);
```

Comment: Oh! Thank you. I did not noticed that... This worked, indeed. I went and got the exact path for my array inside the object and it worked... Thank you @technophyle